# ElasticSearch ConnectionPool using elasticsearch-py library

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am a novice in ElasticSearch, and trying to add entries to an index in ElasticSearch using concurrent connections from the ElasticSearch ConnectionPool [via the `Transport class`].

Here is my code:

```
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.transport import Transport

def init_connection():
    transport = Transport([{'host':SERVER_URL}], port=SERVER_PORT, randomize_hosts=False)
    transport.add_connection(host=SERVER_URL+SERVER_PORT)
    return transport

def add_entries_to_es(id, name):
    transport = init_connection()
    doc = {
           'name': name,
           'postDate': datetime.datetime.now(),
           'valid': "true",
           'suggest': {
               "input": name,
               'output': name,
               'payload': {'domain_id': id}
               }
           }
    conn = transport.getConnection()
    es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(connection_class=conn)
    res = es.index(index=ES_INDEX_NAME, doc_type=ES_DOC_TYPE, id=id, body=doc)
    ...
```

And I get the below error:

```
File "/my_project/elastichelper.py", line 23, in init_connection
transport.add_connection(host=SERVER_URL+SERVER_PORT)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 139, in add_connection
self.set_connections(self.hosts)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 169, in set_connections
connections = map(_create_connection, hosts)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 161, in _create_connection
kwargs.update(host)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

I'm not sure if `Transport class` is the right way to instantiate a `ConnectionPool` in ElasticSearch.  However, I read from docs that [Transport class](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/connection.html#transport) handles instantiation of the individual connections as well as creating a connection pool to hold them.

I'm not getting the correct way to instantiate a `ConnectionPool` and use the connections efficiently from the pool. Reading and googling hasn't helped in my favor.

I am also aware about the [helpers.bulk()](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk) API, but I'm confused about using it since along with adding entries to index, I'm deleting the invalid entries as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that simply using the `ElasticSearch` classes instance with an appropriate `timeout` value set [*for me,* `timeout=30` *was good enough*] for the `index` method worked. Like this:

```
doc = {
       'name': name,
       'postDate': datetime.datetime.now(),
       'valid': "true",
       'suggest': {
           "input": name,
           'output': name,
           'payload': {'domain_id': id}
           }
       }
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()
res = es.index(index=ES_INDEX_NAME, doc_type=ES_DOC_TYPE, id=id, body=doc, timeout=30)
```

I had initially faced `timeout` issues with simple `ElasticSearch` class instance, which was fixed by the above changes.

I din't have to use `Transport` or `Connection` class instances explicitly at all.